# How to join two tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get table C from table A and table B in one select statement?  Thanks.

```
Table A -
Product, Date, Price 
P1, 2018-01-01, 10
P2, 2018-01-02, 20

Table B - 
Date
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04

Table C
Product, Date, Price
P1, 2018-01-01, 10 
P1, 2018-01-02, null
P1, 2018-01-03, null
P1, 2018-01-04, null
P2, 2018-01-01, null
P2, 2018-01-02, 20 
P2, 2018-01-03, null
P2, 2018-01-04, null
```

Comment: did you get your answer here? @JohnSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` will create a full cross product between the tables. Then you can fill in the `Price` column when the dates match.

```
SELECT
  Product,
  TableB.Date,
  IF(TableA.Date = TableB.Date, Price, NULL END) AS Price
FROM TableA
CROSS JOIN TableB
ORDER BY Product, Date
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b17aa/29)

Answer (score 0):

since you need all the rows from table A with all the dates in tables B, you need to use FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b
ON a.date = b.date
```

but since, there is no full outer join in My sql you can emulate it by using this post: [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)
in MYSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON a.date=B.date
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A a 
RIGHT JOIN table_B b
ON a.date=b.date
```

Comment: That solution doesn't produce the output requested by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

select ta.product , tb.Date , ta.Price
from TableA ta, Table